# Adding a value at specific index in Postgresql

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I need to assign the result of a function to an array like I used to do using Oracle:

```
DECLARE
  array array_t := array_t(); -- Initialise it
  v_idx NUMBER:=0;

BEGIN
    v_idx:= v_idx+1;
    array.extend;
    array(v_idx):= regexp_replace(
                  'HELLO WORLD', '(^|[^a-z0-9])' || 'HELLO' || '($|[^a-z0-9])', 
                  '\1' || 'GOOD BYE' || '\2', 1, 0,  'i');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('array(v_idx): '||array(v_idx)||' ,v_idx: '||v_idx);

END;
/
```

In PostgreSQL, I have tried this without successful results:

```
DECLARE
  x_array VARCHAR[];
  idx INTEGER:=1;

BEGIN 
  x_array[idx]:=string_to_array(SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('HELLO WORLD','(^|[^a-z0-9])' || 'HELLO' || '($|[^a-z0-9])','\1' || 'GOOD BYE' || '\2','g')))
  RAISE NOTICE 'x_array:% ', x_array;
END;
/
```

How can you handle to store strings in an array and store/retrieve using index value? Should I use other object to be able to get/put elements by index?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why are you calling `string_to_array`?

Answer (score 0):

First, anonymous blocks in Postgres are identified by "DO" and are dollar quoted ($$...$$). Secondly your adding a string to an array not adding an array to an array (see concat array) so you don't require the String _to_array function, nor are you required to "Select" from the regex, just extract. With these in mind your anonymous block becomes:

```
do $$
declare
  x_array varchar[];
  idx integer:=1;
begin 
  x_array[idx]:=regexp_replace('HELLO WORLD','(^|[^a-z0-9])' || 'HELLO' || '($|[^a-z0-9])','\1' || 'GOOD BYE' || '\2','g');
  raise notice 'x_array:% ', x_array;
end; 
$$;
```